# How to create a Locust task for a dynamic list of URLs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, locust

I'm trying to get timing information for *all* my API endpoints based on the OpenAPI JSON, so I would like to do something like this in the `setup` method:

```
for api_path in self.client.get('/api/doc/?format=openapi').json()['paths'].keys():
    self.get_[api_path] = [@task decorated method which retrieves the API path]
```

Or is there another way to generate tasks at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in the [API docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.core.TaskSet.schedule_task):

```
def setup(self) -> None:
    for api_path in self.client.get('/api/doc/?format=openapi').json()['paths'].keys():
        self.schedule_task(self.api_task, args=[api_path])

def api_task(self, path: str) -> None:
    response = self.client.get("/api{}?limit=1000".format(path))
    assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK, response.content.decode()
```

Comment: This is deprecated in locust 1.0 but the doc hasn't been updated.