# How can I perform Load testing with Locust using PyTest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, locust

What do you think is it possible to perform Load testing using PyTest?
For example:

```
import locust

class UsersTest(locust.TaskSet):

    @locust.seq_task(1)
    def api_get_task(self):
        self.client.get("/api", name="GET /api") # Самое действие

    @locust.seq_task(2)
    def api_post_task(self):
        payload = {"username": "user1", "password": "123456"}
        self.client.post("/api", data=payload, name="POST /api")

class SituationTest(locust.HttpLocust):

    task_set = UsersTest 
    min_wait = 1000 
    max_wait = 2000
    host = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

So here is example of 2 simple tasks for 2 urls. Into class UsersTest I have my test cases itself. Into class SituationTest I have my params.

So question is how to integrate this 2 classes into pytest fixtures decorators and split it between test_file.py and conftest.py?

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can use `locust` as a library instead of as a CLI.

```
import gevent
import locust


class UsersTest(locust.SequentialTaskSet):

    @locust.task
    def api_get_task(self):
        self.client.get("/api", name="GET /api")  # Самое действие

    @locust.task
    def api_post_task(self):
        payload = {"username": "user1", "password": "123456"}
        self.client.post("/api", data=payload, name="POST /api")


class SituationTest(locust.HttpUser):

    task_set = UsersTest
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 2000
    host = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"


def test__your_pytest_example():
    env = locust.env.Environment(user_classes=[SituationTest])
    env.create_local_runner()
    gevent.spawn(locust.stats.stats_history, env.runner)
    env.runner.start(1, spawn_rate=1)
    gevent.spawn_later(10, lambda: env.runner.quit())
    env.runner.greenlet.join()

    assert env.stats.total.avg_response_time < 60
    assert env.stats.total.num_failures == 0
    assert env.stats.total.get_response_time_percentile(0.95) < 100
```

Check the official doc: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do this by adding individual pytest tests as a locust task.

If you tests are simple and don't use pytest fixtures, you can import all test functions(or classes) and add them as tasks.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450966/2312300) is how you can add a task programmatically.

Resulting code would be something of this effect.

```
from test_module import test_a
from locust import TaskSet, HttpLocust


class TestTaskSet(TaskSet):
     @task
     def test_task(self):
         self.schedule_task(test_a)


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = TestTaskSet
```

If your test code uses pytest features like fixtures, parameterization etc., you can use `pytest.main()` to collect all the tests and add individual tests as tasks and execute them as pytest tests.

e.g.

```
import pytest
from locust import TaskSet, HttpLocust, between


class TestCollector:

    def __init__(self):
        self.collected = []

    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, items):
        for item in items:
            self.collected.append(item.nodeid)


test_collector = TestCollector()

pytest.main(['tests_dir', '--collect-only'], plugins=[test_collector])


class TestTaskSet(TaskSet):

    @task
    def task_gen(self):
        for test in test_collector.collected:
            self.schedule_task(pytest.main, args=[test])


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = TestTaskSet
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
```

This code will make individual tests a locust task.

Comment: This code may be outdated due to changes in locust. Locust made same breaking changes when it was upgraded to 1.0 release.