# How to run locust in pytest

Tags: pytest, locust

I have many test cases written by pytest. I am now going to use locust to write some concurrency-related test cases. I found that locust needs to execute a command line first, and then enter some parameters on the user interface to execute these use cases. Can I execute locust directly through pytest code? If an error is reported during execution, the test case will be directly terminated and marked as failed. I hope I can run all test cases (the test cases I wrote before and the test cases written using locust) using pytest command directly.

Comment: Please check it - [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Locust as a library to run it via code instead of command line.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html

Then for doing any pytest asserts, you could use Locust event hooks.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html

I haven't done this with pytest, but I think I should work.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, welcome to StackOverflow, zhoujiazhi. I believe you will find the answer for your question on [this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914502/how-can-i-perform-load-testing-with-locust-using-pytest).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this answer does not seem to be what I want. I want the multi-threading function of locust and add it to my pytest as a multi-threading module. Can you briefly describe how to execute locust directly in pytest?

Comment: Ok, this is a bit different than what I understood from your original question. Are you maybe referring to [across multiple machines](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html)?